# Read csv into pandas dataframe but avoid NaN rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that has 73 rows of data and 16 columns and I want to read it and pass it to a pandas dataframe but when I do

```
data_dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep = ',')
```

I get 3152 rows and 22 columns with 73 rows and 16 columns of data and the rest just pure NaN values. How can I tell pandas to read the valid rows and columns data and avoid all these extra NaN ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a visualization of the whole data

```
import seaborn as sn
sn.heatmap(data_dataframe.isna())
```

and then if u want to remove rows that have "nan" use

```
data_dataframe.dropna()
```

and if u want to remove continuous rows use (by default axis = 0 so no need to specify it)

```
data_dataframe.drop(index = data_dataframe.index[1:3], inplace = True)
```

and if u want to remove any specific rows use

```
data_dataframe.drop(index = [1,3,5], inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple function for it:

given a data frame `df`, use the following `df. dropna()` function.